# deleting data in core data entity when before restkit mapping

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I am developing an iPad app which loads data from the server by using RestKit.

The data on the server can be changed from multiple sources. I have a pull to refresh functionality in the iPad App using which I pull the updated data from the server (pull the data from the server, store it in core data and display them in the table). Whenever I pull the data from the server, the core data entity is not updated with the current data even though I see the updated data in the json payload (from restkit logs).

Please help me to fix this issue by explaining with an example.

I already saw few posts regards to this but not very related to my problem.

Comment: Show your code, and a trace log showing the updated JSON not being applied

Comment: @Wain Thanks for your response. I was able to resolve the issue by adding addFetchRequestBlock to clean up the orphaned objects.